# Why is my Python3 pip package not working eventhough it shows on PyPi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, bitcoin

Here is a little library that I'm trying to make available on PyPi for others to use.

https://github.com/rojavacrypto/python-libbitcoin

I use this command to upload the package:

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload
```

I also tried this:

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_egg upload
```

Both seem to run fine without errors, and it's even [listed on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libbitcoin)

But for some reason when I try to pip install on Ubuntu, it gives me an error.

```
# pip3 install libbitcoin
Collecting libbitcoin
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libbitcoin (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libbitcoin
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your package in PyPI is "python-libbitcoin":

```
pip3 install python-libbitcoin
```

and here you go:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-libbitcoin
  http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-libbitcoin/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if pypi.python.org has it available
  Downloading python-libbitcoin-1.2.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/lukas/x/build/python-libbitcoin/setup.py) egg_info for package python-libbitcoin
```

Comment: damn that's embarassing... Thanks.